# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when using ORKESerializer

Tags: xcode, swift, researchkit

The past couple weeks I have been developing a ResearchKit app. I have run into some errors when I try to turn my survey data into JSON. I added some serialization code and when I try to run I get these two errors. Please find the below screenshot for more information.

[image]

I have tried changing the architectures in Build Settings but to no avail. How do I fix this?
ORKESerializer code:

```
let decodedData = try ORKESerializer.JSONDataForObject(data)

print("decoded data: \(decodedData)")

if let jsonString = NSString(data: decodedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {

      print(jsonString)

}
```

My bridging header code:

```
#import "ORKESerialization.h"
```

My architectures/valid architectures:

```
$(ARCHS_STANDARD)
x86_64
```

Comment: Please clone the latest stable branch. This bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like by default, the ORKESerializer class isn't part of the ResearchKit framework. (See [this comment](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/issues/131#issuecomment-97302800).) It may be included in the tests, however.

To use it in your app, the code needs to be compiled/linked in, so you need to add ORKESerialization.m to one of your targets.

Comment: Also, you'll need a version of RK that includes this recently merged [PR](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/pull/663) which fixes an issue when archiving a project containing `ORKESerializer`.

Comment: Now I am getting the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Expected valid JSON object'

Comment: Did you pass a valid JSON object to it? ;)

Comment: I am passing the result of the survey. Do I need to do anything else first? It is still in UTF8.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work, needed to declare the result as it's own variable. Thank you so much for your help!